# I'm racking my head and can't figure out why I'm getting No value associated with key CodingKeys error

Tags: swift, combine

I've been racking my head for the last day trying to figure out why I'm getting the error below.  I've tried changing from an array to a dictionary and no luck.

```
failure(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "datalist", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"datalist\", intValue: nil) (\"datalist\").", underlyingError: nil)))
```

I'm using `Combine` and I can see that I'm getting data pack using Postman.

Here's the beginning part of my struct

```
struct WelcomeList: Codable , Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let datalist: [DATUMVAList]
    let links: Links
    let meta: MetaVAList
}

// MARK: - DATUMVAList
struct DATUMVAList: Codable {
    let id, type: String
    let attributes: AttributesVAList
}
```

Here's my function and I'm failing at the completion part.

```
typealias vaNearbyList = [WelcomeList]

    class VAFacilityNearbyList: ObservableObject {
        struct AppError {
            // swiftlint:disable:next identifier_name
            let errorString: String
        }
    
        @Published var vaNearbyList: [WelcomeList] = []
        @Published var errorResponse: String = ""
        var locationIDData: [String] = []
        var cancellabes = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        var appError: AppError? = nil
    
        enum UserFetchError: Error {
            case badServerResponse
            case urlEmpty
            case other
        }
    
        func getNearByVAFacilitiesInfo(idArray: [String]) {
            // We need to create the URL to get the list of facilities
            var vaURL = "https://sandbox-api.va.gov/services/va_facilities/v0/facilities?ids="
            for vaID in idArray {
                vaURL += ",\(vaID)"
            }
            print("\(#function) vaURL \(vaURL)")
    
            var URLBuilder = URLComponents(string: vaURL) //vha_659BZ,vha_544gc
            guard let url = URLBuilder?.url else { return }
    
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    //        request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue(VA_API_Key, forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
    
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .tryMap { (returnData, response) -> Data in
                    guard
                        let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                          response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                              self.appError = AppError(errorString: "\(UserFetchError.badServerResponse)")
                              throw UserFetchError.badServerResponse
                    }
                    print("\(#function) response \(response.statusCode)")
                    print("\(#function) returning data \(returnData)")
                    return returnData
                }
                .decode(type: WelcomeList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .sink { (completion) in
                    print("\(#function) completion - \(completion)")
                } receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedVAListData) in
                    print("\(#function) returnedData - \(returnedVAListData)")
                    self?.vaNearbyList = [returnedVAListData]
                }
                .store(in: &cancellabes)
        }
    }
```

Here's the data I'm getting back.  Thanks!

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "vha_544GC",
            "type": "va_facilities",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Rock Hill VA Clinic",
                "facility_type": "va_health_facility",
                "classification": "Primary Care CBOC",
                "website": "https://www.columbiasc.va.gov/locations/RockHill.asp",
                "lat": 34.97720057,
                "long": -81.02445796,
                "time_zone": "America/New_York",
                "address": {
                    "mailing": {},
                    "physical": {
                        "zip": "29732-1836",
                        "city": "Rock Hill",
                        "state": "SC",
                        "address_1": "2670 Mills Park Drive",
                        "address_2": null,
                        "address_3": null
                    }
                },
                "phone": {
                    "fax": "803-325-1612",
                    "main": "803-366-4848",
                    "pharmacy": "888-651-2683",
                    "after_hours": "803-776-4000 x57200",
                    "patient_advocate": "803-776-4000 x56937",
                    "mental_health_clinic": "803-325-9526",
                    "enrollment_coordinator": "803-776-4000 x55815"
                },
                "hours": {
                    "friday": "800AM-430PM",
                    "monday": "800AM-430PM",
                    "sunday": "Closed",
                    "tuesday": "800AM-430PM",
                    "saturday": "Closed",
                    "thursday": "800AM-430PM",
                    "wednesday": "800AM-430PM"
                },
                "operational_hours_special_instructions": null,
                "services": {
                    "other": [],
                    "health": [
                        "Audiology",
                        "Dermatology",
                        "MentalHealthCare",
                        "PrimaryCare",
                        "SpecialtyCare"
                    ],
                    "last_updated": "2022-01-16"
                },
                "satisfaction": {
                    "health": {
                        "primary_care_urgent": 0.7400000095367432,
                        "primary_care_routine": 0.8500000238418579
                    },
                    "effective_date": "2021-03-05"
                },
                "wait_times": {
                    "health": [
                        {
                            "service": "Audiology",
                            "new": 52.25,
                            "established": 2.35
                        },
                        {
                            "service": "Dermatology",
                            "new": 0.125,
                            "established": 2.333333
                        },
                        {
                            "service": "MentalHealthCare",
                            "new": 30.17647,
                            "established": 4.017241
                        },
                        {
                            "service": "PrimaryCare",
                            "new": 14.3125,
                            "established": 1.52759
                        },
                        {
                            "service": "SpecialtyCare",
                            "new": 38.133333,
                            "established": 3.304347
                        }
                    ],
                    "effective_date": "2022-01-16"
                },
                "mobile": false,
                "active_status": "A",
                "operating_status": {
                    "code": "NORMAL"
                },
                "detailed_services": null,
                "visn": "7"
            }
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "self": "https://sandbox-api.va.gov/services/va_facilities/v0/facilities?ids=vha_544GC&page=1&per_page=10",
        "first": "https://sandbox-api.va.gov/services/va_facilities/v0/facilities?ids=vha_544GC&page=1&per_page=10",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null,
        "last": "https://sandbox-api.va.gov/services/va_facilities/v0/facilities?ids=vha_544GC&page=1&per_page=10"
    },
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "current_page": 1,
            "per_page": 10,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "total_entries": 1
        },
        "distances": []
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for this to be debugged, you would need to show the data you’re trying to parse.

Comment: Your JSON doesn’t match, like the error says. See how they JSON says “data” and your model says “datalist”? There may be other errors, but that was the first one I spotted. Paste your JSON into app.quicktype.io and compare your models.

Comment: Ah let me explore that.  I was using quicktype for a couple different structs and I changed the name for redeclaration error. Thank you

Comment: So I made this change, but now I get the error `"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."` which doesn't make sense since I'm not decode is not of an array type `.decode(type: WelcomeList.self`

Comment: You’d have to show your complete code for your models that you’re trying to debug this. Is it exactly what QuickType is spitting out?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the decoder to decode something that has the fields of a `WelcomeList`:

```
let id = UUID()
let datalist: [DATUMVAList]
let links: Links
let meta: MetaVAList
```

The top level keys in your JSON are:

```
{
  "data": ...
  "links": ...
  "meta": ...
}
```

The error is telling you it is looking for a key named `datalist` and can't find one.

To solve the problem you're either going to have to rename the field to `data` or use `CodingKeys` to tell the system that the field of your struct named `datalist` is found with a key named `data`.

See the [Encoding and Decoding documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types/) under the heading "Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys"